# Hibernate (HQL) select query with list of ids as parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to requirement to fetch product information from the product table by product_code.
so, I have to pass a list of product_code to my select query with the help of WHERE Clause IN.

Am able to pass list of product_code but its returning only one product information ( select query giving results for the first product_code).

Please find my code below that am having issue.

```
public JSONArray getUpdatedProductDescription(List<String> product_code_list)
    {
        Collection<String> produceCollection=product_code_list;
        List<String> code = null;

        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
        cfg.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
        Session session=factory.openSession();  
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction(); 

        String hql = "from Product where code in(:code)"; 


        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameterList("code", produceCollection);
        List<Product> listProducts = query.list();

        for(Product prod : listProducts)
        {
            System.out.println("Product Details:::"+prod.getCode());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the raw query should return more than one record?

Comment: yes. i tested it by hardcode multiple values. its working fine. After that only am trying by pass as parameter  ( dynamically ).

Comment: Are you using an old version of Hibernate by any chance?  Are you certain that `produceCollection` has something in it?

Comment: Print produceCollection to ensure it has values

Comment: am using Hibernate-core 3.6.3 Final . yes, am getting list of product_code from produceCollection.. No problem from that..

Comment: Finally its working. Problem with the input data. Thanks to all